# aggregate by distance in R

Tags: r, aggregation

I have a data set of road traffic data for certain roads, and I have a few columns in my data set. One of them is "Distance from start" (starts from 0 until the end of the road, in unit meters.), and another column is: "Speed".
I want to find out the average speed along the road in intervals of about 5000 meters. How can I do it using aggregation or some other approch?
[image]
 This is my data set, which has about 700,000 rows. It is sorted by DistanceFromStart.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the dataset. i.e Type `dput(head(yourdataset))` on your R console and  copy/paste the output in your post

Comment: Try `aggregate(Speed~cbind(Distance=cut(DistancefromStart, breaks=seq(0,max(DistancefromStart), by=5000), include.lowest=TRUE), df1, FUN=mean)` (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `cut` to create the groups and then get the `mean` of "Speed"

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Speed=mean(Speed)), by=list(cut(DistancefromStart,
   breaks= seq(0, max(DistancefromStart)+5000, by = 5000),
                 include.lowest=TRUE))]
```